# C# DataSet from MySql table parser with database fieldname in property

Tags: c#, mysql, dataset, mapping

So I am working on a basic MySql data parser to one of my models and I just wat to generate a generic Get method for this instead of having to map every database table to a model.

The way I want to do this possible but I do not know how. I will show you some code.

```
public class DatabaseHandler
{

    public DatabaseHandler()
    {

    }

    public DataSet Get<T>(string field = "id", string oper = ">", string input = "0") where T : BaseDataModel
    {
        DataSet ds = null;
        using (var conn = Connection())
        {
            string query = string.Format("SELECT * FROM {0} WHERE {1} {2} {3}", typeof(T).Name.ToLower(), field, oper, input);
            using (MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, conn))
            {
                ds = new DataSet();
                adapter.Fill(ds);
            }
        }

        return ds;
    }

    private MySqlConnection Connection()
    {
        return new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;database=trainingsschema;uid=trainingsschema;pwd=password;");
    }

}
```

Then my model I currently have:

```
public class Onderdeel : BaseDataModel
{
    public Onderdeel() : base() { }

    public virtual string Naam { get; set; }
}
```

Base:

```
public class BaseDataModel
{
    public BaseDataModel()
    {

    }

    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

}
```

So if I want to parse the result of this dataset to a `List<Onderdeel>` I would have to map every table there is outside of this `DatabaseHandler.Get<T>()` method. Which I would do by using this code:

```
myDataSet.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
.Select(i => new ClassName() {
  i.MyProperty = dataRow.Field<String>("MyDatabaseFieldName")
}.ToList();
```

What I want to archieve is a simple mapper where the database field names are in the metadata of the propery.

So my Model would become something like this:

```
[FieldName("identifier")]
public virtual int Id { get; set; }

[FieldName("naam")]
public virtual string Name { get; set; }
```

And then I would like to replace the

```
i.MyProperty = dataRow.Field<String>("MyDatabaseFieldName")
```

With a loop that would go thru all properties of my model and map them to the "FieldName" I attached to it, also DataType wouldn't be a problem because it is there. Finally the `DatabaseHandler.Get<T>()` can then return a `List<T>` instead of `DataSet`.

Who can help me?

Answer (score 0):

After some hours nobody responded here so I had to do some investigation. For anyone who is trying to do this:

1. Add a new class called `FieldName`

   ```
   [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
   public class FieldName : Attribute
   {
       public FieldName(string text)
       {
           this.Text = text;
       }

       public string Text { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. Make sure you have a basemodel like me and extend any database models with this, also add the `FieldName` attribute to every mappable property

   ```
   public class BaseDataModel
   {
       public BaseDataModel()
       {

       }

       [FieldName("id")]
       public int Id { get; set; }

   }
   ```
3. Add this database helper to your project (of course you can implement my code as well)

   ```
   public class DatabaseHandler
   {

   public DatabaseHandler()
   {

   }

   public List<T> Get<T>(string field = "id", string oper = ">", string input = "0") where T : BaseDataModel
   {
       List<T> list = new List<T>();
       DataSet ds = null;
       using (var conn = Connection())
       {
           string query = string.Format("SELECT * FROM {0} WHERE {1} {2} {3}", typeof(T).Name.ToLower(), field, oper, input);
           using (MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, conn))
           {
               ds = new DataSet();
               adapter.Fill(ds);
           }

           foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
           {
               object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));

               foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in typeof(T).GetProperties())
               {
                   if (propertyInfo.CanWrite && propertyInfo.CanRead)
                   {
                       string fieldName = propertyInfo.CustomAttributes.ElementAt(0).ConstructorArguments[0].Value.ToString();

                       if (fieldName == null) continue;

                       propertyInfo.SetValue(obj, row.Field<dynamic>(fieldName));
                   }
               }

               list.Add(obj as T);
           }
       }

       return list;
   }

   private MySqlConnection Connection()
   {
       return new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;database=trainingsschema;uid=trainingsschema;pwd=password;");
   }

   }
   ```
4. This is plug and play it you have only 1 attribute to your properties if you have more you might want to filter on the right custom attribute and their values.
5. Now you can call any `List<T>` from your database like this:

   ```
   List<Onderdeel> onderdelen = _db.Get<Onderdeel>();
   ```